# How to get all content from Shared Preferences in flutter

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

I want to get all sharedprefrences content (key,value).Is it possibly?Is there a possibility  to iterate by keys?

```
getStringValues() async   
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance()
    String stringValue = prefs.getString('key');
    return stringValue;
  }
```

Answer (score 11):

Use `SharedPreferences.getKeys()` to get all keys and then get their values with a for loop like this:

```
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance()
final keys = prefs.getKeys();

final prefsMap = Map<String, dynamic>();
for(String key in keys) {
   prefsMap[key] = prefs.get(key);
}

print(prefsMap);
```

Comment: I found this answer, used it, and then noticed I edited and upvoted it in oct 2020 lol. Thanks again 

Answer (score 2):

```
SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((data){
    data.getKeys().forEach((key){
      print(key+"="+data.get(key));
    });
});
```